# Pub finished with exit code 69

Tags: android, flutter, dart, connection-timeout, pubspec

While installing tflite package in my flutter application .. flutter pub get is not working after few minutes it shows connection timeout server unavailable though other packages are getting installed.

Comment: Please add your pub spec.yaml to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this Go to Environment variables**(This PC(My Computer) >Properties>Advanced System Settings> New environment variable)** then add this two variables **VariableName:** FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL **VariableValue:** https://storage.flutter-io.cn and **VariableName:** PUB_HOSTED_URL **VariableValue:** https://pub.flutter-io.cn

Comment: Surprisingy, this worked for me. But just wondering why ".cn"? Isn't there a global repository url available?